# This site can't be reached after wordpress migration

Tags: 18.04, apache2, login, wordpress

I've just migrated a fresh site without any error. All the images, links and icons have migrated successfully. But the one error I keep getting is when I click on the login link.

```
This site can’t be reached. site.com refused to connect.
```

I'm trying to login to the WordPress Site that I've just migrated but every time it's clicked, it would take me to that error message.

I've entered the following in the URL:

```
http://site.com/wp-login.php 
http://site.com/wp-admin.php
```

I have my database in phpMyAdmin. I'm using the latest version of Ubuntu 18.04. Any help on how to solve this error and access the login page would be appreciated.

In the error log, I get the following:

**Unable to open**

`/var/www/html/.../wordpress/wp-content/wflogs/ips.php for reading and writing.`

Comment: This is a Wordpress question rather than a Ubuntu question. Have you tried [overriding the home and site url](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) in `wp-config`?

Comment: @Jos Hey Jos, Yes I have already done that. The site is loading but I can't login to Wordpress.

Comment: Is there a directory `wflogs` in `wp-content`?

Comment: No there isn't a directory called wflogs which is why It's confusing.

Comment: So create one. Wordfence is trying to write a log file to that directory but it can't create by itself. If that doesn't help, temporarily remove the whole Wordfence plugin folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I think there is an issue with the Custom Design. So please do check before submitting the migration.